# Display twitter tweets for own account in drupal 6

Tags: 7, social-network

Suppose My twitter account is drupaltest so I want to display all the mentions of #drupaltest or @drupaltest on the Drupal 6 website. Looking at the twitter module http://drupal.org/project/twitter but that one is a little confusing. So let me know whats the best way to post tweets for your accounts on the Drupal 6 website? I am not looking for any reverse functionality of posting on twitter through my website, just want to display those tweets.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way is definitely to install the Twitter module that you have already discovered. I used to do this on my website as a way of pulling in tweets to my blog. You will only need the read-only configuration for the module, and you may find it easiest to use the Views integration.

If you'd rather code your own, the QueryPath module allows you to write jQuery-like requests directly against Twitter's API, but you'll have to write your own module. (You can start with the sample modules that come with QueryPath).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not familiar with the Twitter module, but I know Twitter has a profile widget at http://twitter.com/about/resources/widgets/widget_profile which will generate javascript you can use to insert a twitter block on your site.

Comment: I saw an example of this and did this. It introduced a bug for me that it shows some old tweets whenever the page loads. Although its a good idea and thanks for the response.